# Looping in avconv with -codec copy

Tags: debian, video-streaming, video-encoding, libav

This is the command I'm using:

```
avconv -loop -1 -re -i "$SOURCE" -codec copy -f flv "$FACEBOOK_URL/$KEY"
```

I'm struggling with some performance issues when I run `avconv` on my server to stream a video file continuously. To reduce CPU load, I pre-encoded my video file and used `-codec copy` to stream it as-is. The problem is that when I use copy, the loop functionality no longer works correctly. (That is, it takes 20-30 seconds to resume playback after the video ends.)  Looping seems fine when I'm re-encoding on the fly, but performance is poor enough that this isn't an option.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I loop in `avconv` without having to re-encode the video every time it loops?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by adding the following option:

```
 -analyzeduration 0
```

The final command I used is:

```
avconv -analyzeduration 0 -loop -1 -re -i "$SOURCE" -codec copy -f flv "$FACEBOOK_URL/$KEY"
```